# Why not checking connectivity while the app is launching?

Tags: android, performance, connection

I'm trying to find a reason why the most popular apps like Facebook, Skype, Twitter, Path... and many others don't require checking connection or server availability while the app is launching. All of them check it while logging in after click Log in button (I don't mean check username and password).

Is there some reason why they are not checking it while app is launching?

Answer (score 0):

What should they suppose to do if they found that there is not connectivity?? the maximum they can show a connection error message. And, most of the apps has a kind of one time login. so no need to worry on the login page

Comment: It can be little inconvenient for apps you must to fill forms every time (because app doesn't remember username and password for security reason). User need to fill in forms and after clicks Log in, app will alert him for connection problem. I believe I can alert the user before he filled in the login form if app has some problem with connectivity. I'm just trying to find a reason why other apps don't solve a situation like this. Maybe for apps like social networks it isn't that important to care about.

Comment: However I wanted to be sure if there is some real reason why not check connectivity when app is launching or not. Thanks.